# \newcommand to define shortcut with optional argument (derivative package)

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

The recent release (June 2021) of the [derivative](https://ctan.org/pkg/derivative?lang=en) package includes the command `\odif` which can be used to typeset differentials.

For instance, `\odif[order={3}]{x}` yields something like `d^3x`.

Because I am replacing the physics package, I would like to add a `\newcommand` which replaces `\dd[3]{x}` with `\odif[order={3}]{x}`.

I know that `\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\odif{#1}}` would replace `\dd{x}` with `\odif{x}` but I don't know how to handle the optional argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply a marker when the optional argument is empty to decide if there is an optional argument.

```
\newcommand*\dd[2][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\odif{#2}\else \odif[order={#1}]{#2}\fi}
```

`xparse` has a mechanism for this:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\dd{ o m }{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\odif{#2}}{\odif[order={#1}]{#2}}}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `xparse` or `NewDocumentCommand`?